# Ruby/Rails ternary and range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range, ternary-operator

I want to filter a parameter if it falls within a range of 1 to 100.

Controller:

```
@range = search_range(params[:range])
```

Helper:

```
def search_range(range)
  range = range.to_i
  range == 1..100 ? range : 30
end
```

But it's always returns 30... tried many things and normal "if/else" but want ternary operator.
Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What does `params[:range]` return?

Comment: Problem is that search_range always return 30...

Comment: @Stefan ...unless you have monkey-patched `Integer#==`.

Comment: @Stefan indeed :)

Comment: An integer. Just want to check if params[:range] is between 1..100. If not return 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just want to check if params[:range] is between 1..100. If not return 30

This should work:

```
def search_range(range)
  range = range.to_i
  range.between?(1, 100) ? range : 30
end
```

The problem with your code is that `==` compares objects, i.e.:

```
20 == 1..100
#=> false
```

checks whether the integer `20` is (numerically) equal to the range `1..100`. Of course it's not, `1..100` isn't even a number.

Comment: Wanted a ternary operation solution and great readability thank you !

Comment: I've run a quick benchmark (see my answer) on these options, and this is also the quickest by a stretch...

Answer (score 0):

If your `params[:range]` returns a number, I think you might need something like the following:

```
def search_range(range)
  range = range.to_i
  range == (1..100).include?(range) ? range : 30
end
```

Is that what you mean? I.E. if the 'range' variable is within 1 to 100 return it, else 30?

Update:

I've done a quick benchmark on the options on the page, and `between?` comes up quickest:

```
              user     system      total        real
include?  0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 (  0.239637)
between?  0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.129158)
===       0.290000   0.000000   0.290000 (  0.293817)
```

Comment: Or, rather `(1..100) === range ? range : 30`

Comment: @Stefan: how does default value `30` make sense then? :)

Comment: params[:range] is an integer for a kilometric distance. Like 20. But search_range always return 30

Comment: If that's the case @neocydfr, this should work. I think the parameter name is a little confusing, as mentioned by Stefan (as in a range of numbers v a distance, as you're using it), but would think this'll get you where you need to be :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `(1..100) === range ? range : 30` it's working nice thank you !

Comment: @SRack Yes will change the parameter name, thank you

Comment: @neocydfr: check out an even better version of that in my answer :)

Comment: You ask for an answer and get four :) (I'd probably lean towards @Stefan's, for readability.) Glad it's sorted.